# 320gig hard disk, only 299 shown after installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the effective hard drive size lower than the actual size?](https://superuser.com/questions/71974/why-is-the-effective-hard-drive-size-lower-than-the-actual-size)

I just purchased a Dell Inspiron 1410 without OS. In the BIOS, it shows 320 GB of hard disk space. After I installed Windows 7 Ultimate, only 299 GB total hard disk space is shown. I only got one partition. I run a partition manager, it shows only 299 GB, without any partition that has the other 20 GB.

Can somebody try to explain what had happen? What will I do so I can use all of the 320 GB.

Answer (score 14):

The BIOS (or the HD manufacturer) is measuring with 1 GB = 10<sup>9</sup> bytes = 1.000.000.000 bytes.

The Windows file dialog seems to count in [GibiBytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte), where 1 GiB = 2<sup>30</sup> bytes = 1.073.741.824 bytes

Checking the numbers, **299 * 2<sup>30</sup>** is approximately **320 * 10<sup>9</sup>**.

Answer (score 8):

Basically a 320GB disk isn't 320GB, it's to do with the mixed use of 1000 and 1024 (2<sup>10</sup>) between marketing and operating system, never expect the full amount OK.

Comment: actually, a 320GB disk is 320GB, just read the [units(7) man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/units.7.html)

Comment: It's not a mix-up between marketing and operating system, it's a mix-up between the metric system and lazy programmers.