# Why can i store only 465 GB in 500 GB hard disk?

Tags: storage, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the effective hard drive size lower than the actual size?](https://superuser.com/questions/71974/why-is-the-effective-hard-drive-size-lower-than-the-actual-size)

If one buys a 500 GB hard disk, why it shows only 465 GB. Where does the extra space go? Same for other secondary storage devices like pen drives. What is the reason?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/373579/is-it-true-that-1-mb-can-mean-either-1000000-bytes-1024000-bytes-or-1048576-by

Answer (score 9):

1 kilobyte is actually 1024 bytes. So

```
500,000,000,000 / (1024*1024*1024) = 465.66 GB
```

[from howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/123268/windows-hard-drive-wrong-capacity/):

> To a hard disk manufacturer, one KB is 1000 bytes, one MB is 1000 KB, and one GB is 1000 MB. Essentially, if a hard disk is advertised as 500GB, it contains 500 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 = 500,000,000,000 bytes of space.
>
> However, manufacturers of RAM don’t sell it in even groups of 1000 – they use groups of 1024. When you’re buying memory, a KB is 1024 bytes, a MB is 1024 KB, and a GB is 1024 MB.
>
> Unfortunately, Windows has always calculated hard drives as powers of 1024 while hard drive manufacturers use powers of 1000.

Comment: 500 **Marketing** GByte (1000*1000*1000 bytes) = 465 **Engineering** GByte (1024*1024*1024) :-)

Comment: See also [KibiByte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)

Answer (score 0):

That's because 500 GB (for sellers) means 500.000.000.000 bytes, which are not exactly `500* (1024*1024*1024) = 500 * 1073741824`, where `1073741824` is the number of bytes of 1 GB.

Comment: In addition, some of the storage space goes in the format of the drive. MBR, file allocation tables, etc.